# HttpGet ActionResult method not all code paths return a value

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .Net Core project where I am trying to get data from the database, but the ActionResult method that is called Get() is showing a compiler error. I initially tried with return Ok as a return statement but the problem persisted, I removed the return statement and I am still seeing an error, 'not all code paths return a value'. There is another question that is asking about a post method that might be similar. But this one is about GET with a return Ok statement.

The problem:

[HttpGet] method not working:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Value>>> Get()
{
    var values = await _context.Values.ToListAsync();
}
```

Edit: The solution (I was missing the a, and the correct return statement and I also needed to pass *values* to the return statement.

Solution:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Value>>> Get()
{
    var values = await _context.Values.ToListAsync();
    return Ok(values);
}
```

Comment: You need to return something from the method. Show the code and error as text, not images, and read [ask] and show your research for the error message.

Comment: Thank you, I will read the How to Ask and update the question. Your comment and Sergeys below led to a solution. I put "return Ok(values)" which seems to have solved it for now. I'll probably throw up a new question when new problems come. Amazing and quick response here. Love Stack Overflow!

Comment: @DmitryPavlov Thanks for chipping in, I was missing a return statement and I was also missing to pass 'Values' into the return statement, the solution was return Ok(values), I will have a look at the link you suggested for further knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this syntax:

```
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Value>> Get()
{
return context.Values.ToArray();
}
```